# For a drive formatted with ReFS, with a mirror, will it self heal if there is a bad sector?

Tags: windows-8.1, refs

Under Windows 8.1, if I format a drive to ReFS, then add a mirror using Disc Management, will it self heal if there is a bad sector on one of the drives?

Or do I have to use Storage Spaces to take advantage of the self healing capabilities of ReFS?

Comment: Nothing can "heal" a HARDWARE problem.

Comment: @mdpc. Both ZFS and Btrfs can heal a bad sector on one drive by reallocating it, and reading the correct sector from the mirrored drive. A standard, healthy, non-Enterprise hard drive has, on average, one unrecoverable bad sector every 12 terabytes of data read (enterprise hard drives are 10x better than this).

Comment: Hmmm....on the current drives "healing" a bad sector should not be necessary as the internal drive controller will automagically replace bad blocks with blocks in its replacement store.  The only time you are going to see bad blocks is if this store is used up and no doubt at that point your disk is in pretty bad shape anyway.  However, this type of practices might "heal" bad structural integrity caused by software, however a mirror might mirror the problem to the other disk as well.

Comment: @mdpc A properly functioning drive firmware won't relocate a sector until it has been successfully read or overwritten. If you keep trying to read the bad sector without overwriting it, the drive will keep trying to read it until it succeeds or you give up.